# Python, __getitem__, slices, and negative indexes

Tags: python, slice, python-2.x

This is an example of Python's behavior with negative numbers passed in slices:

```
>>> class test:
...     def __getitem__(self, sl):
...          print sl.start, sl.stop, sl.step
...
>>> t = test()
>>> t[0:0:0]
0 0 0
>>> t[-1:0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute '__len__'
>>> def __len__(self): return 100
...
>>> test.__len__ = __len__
>>> t[-1:0]
99 0 None
>>>
```

I want to do my own handling with negative indexes. How can I make Python stop deciding on the slice indexes automagically?

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.x, you need to use new-style classes by subclassing `object`, then you get the original parameters of the slice:

```
>>> class C(object):
...   def __getitem__(self, key):
...     print key
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c[-1:2]
slice(-1, 2, None)
```

Prior to 2.x, there was a dedicated method for slicing, [`__getslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__), which is still supported for in Python 2.x and does the interpolation using `__len__`:

> Called to implement evaluation of self[i:j]. The returned object should be of the same type as self. Note that missing i or j in the slice expression are replaced by zero or sys.maxsize, respectively. **If negative indexes are used in the slice, the length of the sequence is added to that index. If the instance does not implement the __len__() method, an AttributeError is raised**. No guarantee is made that indexes adjusted this way are not still negative. Indexes which are greater than the length of the sequence are not modified. **If no __getslice__() is found, a slice object is created instead, and passed to __getitem__() instead**.

(emphasis mine)